# Can't add a project .net core 2 reference but can add a dll .net core 2 reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reference, .net-core

i don't know why, i can't add a **project library in .Net core 2.0** reference to my **universal windows plateform application (target 10.0.16299)** .

i get this error:

```
unable to add a reference to project '[projectName]'
```

But if i choose to add directly the dll from the project library .Net core 2.0. Everything work well.

So why i can add a dll but not the project reference ? 
If someone have some idea, i will appreciate it, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a target framework compatibility point of view, an UWP project cannot reference a .NET Core 2.0 project since they are incompatible. It may technically work using the dll directly, since the implementations share similarities, but there may be difficulties. The project reference executes a sanity check which fails as expected. When you reference a DLL directly, you are responsible for making sure that it was built for a compatible framework.

To share code between a .NET Core 2.0 app and a recent version of UWP, you need to create a .NET Standard project, since both UWP and .NET Core support .NET Standard.

Comment: Ok , thank you for your answer. The problem is , i have a big library class made in .Net Core 2. Can i switch to .Net Standard ? I hope so

Comment: Oh perfect , i just update the "TargetFramework" in the csproj for set "netstandard2.0" . And now is work very well . Thank you so much